# magento2 cart add multiple configurable product variants showing one product only

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, addtocart

I am trying to add a configurable product with with different variants but its showing one item with 2 quantity instead of showing 2 item with each quantity one.

```
$wholedata = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    $productId =$wholedata['product_id'];
    $superattribute = array();  
    foreach ($wholedata['qty'] as $eachkey => $eachparam) {
        foreach ($wholedata['config'] as $key => $value) {
            $superattribute[$key] = $value[$eachkey];
        }
        $params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            //'product' => $productId, //product Id
            'qty'   =>$eachparam,
            'selected_configurable_option' => '',
            'super_attribute' => $superattribute        
        );     
        $_product = $this->product->load($productId);       
        $this->cart->addProduct($productId, $params);
        $this->cart->save();
    }
```

But Strange when I added it one by one and just refresh the cart page in-between then it works fine
If have tried to use `$quote->collectTotals()->save();` as well `$checkoutsession->getQuote()->setCartWasUpdated(true);` but nothing works.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution i.e

```
$wholedata = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

$productId =$wholedata['product_id'];
$superattribute = array();  
foreach ($wholedata['qty'] as $eachkey => $eachparam) {
    foreach ($wholedata['config'] as $key => $value) {
        $superattribute[$key] = $value[$eachkey];
    }
    $params = array(
        'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
        //'product' => $productId, //product Id
        'qty'   =>$eachparam,
        'selected_configurable_option' => '',
        'super_attribute' => $superattribute        
    );     
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $storeId = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
        $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);  
        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
}
```

Works for me